# Query a jsonb column dynamically in Postgres

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, jsonb

I have a column `carInfo` with type `jsonb` in one of my tables in a PostgreSQL database. A sample row looks something like this:

```
{
   "name":"John",
   "age":25,
   "car":{
      "brand":"KIA",
      "year":2015
   }
}
```

I know that in PostgreSQL you can query it in this way:

```
select * from car where carInfo -> 'name' = 'John'
```

but I would like to make this query dynamic (by using PostgreSQL functions or something) so that I can query it from my Java application. I want to reuse the same query even when I want to go a level deeper for example

```
select * from car where carInfo -> 'car' -> 'brand' = 'KIA'
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the contains operator `@>`

```
select *
from car
where car_info @> '{"name": "John"}';
```

or

```
select *
from car
where car_info @> '{"car": {"Brand": "KIA"}}';
```

In your Java code you can write a single PreparedStatement to deal with both:

```java
String sql = "select * from car where car_info @> cast(? as jsonb)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, "{\"car\": {\"Brand\": \"KIA\"}}";
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Using the `@>` operator has the added benefit, that Postgres can make use of a (GIN) index on that column, which would not be possible with the `->` chain.